# How to build a custom query in Twenty Eleven theme?

Tags: php, wordpress

If somebody give me some ideas, or point me in the right direction it would be great.

I need to build a custom query in Twenty Eleven theme that displays 9 posts on the main page and 1 sticky post on the very bottom. The other pages would display just 10 regular posts.

Can you tell me how would I do that. Is content.php the only file I would need to modify.

Thank you in advance for any info.

Comment: How would you flag or otherwise identify which post you'd like to be sticky?  Are you envisioning something like a custom field that you can set in whichever post you'd like to be sticky?  Also, is the last post (sticky post) going to be styled like the others (so that the user just sees it as the "last" post on the main page?

Comment: I can make a post sticky in the Publish section by selecting "Stick the post to the front page". It would be just one post per entire site. It doesn't need to be styled, or look different than the rest of the posts.

Comment: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-build-a-custom-query-in-twenty-eleven

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the number of posts returned using the query_posts() function. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts

For example:

```
<?php 
    query_posts('showposts=9');
    if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
?>

<a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>

<?php endwhile; ?>


<?php endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```